# How to disable any log for a thread

Tags: log4j

I am using org.apache.log4j.Logger for logging and I am developing a jsp just for monitoring purposes.
This jsp is using classes that write logs (INFO level) not interesting for this monitoring, but annoying, as long as I want to execute this jsp very often.

So, my question is the next:
Is there any way to disable these INFO logs just for the thread where my jsp is running?

If there is not, maybe this approach might pay the bill:
Is there any way to tell log4j level for one given class is FATAL just for a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this using simple log4j config.

However, you can have your code install a custom filter on the appropriate logger.  See the interface reference here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html

1. Construct an object that implements
   the filter you want.
2. Find the logger using LogManager.getLogger("*loggername*")
3. Insert the filter.